# Detect which checkbox is touched? Array Java Android Studio

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-checkbox

I have a `CheckBox` `ArrayList` set up, but how do I know which one is touched? More specifically I simply would like to get the integer value of "i" in the `ArrayList` of which checkbox has been touched. Any ideas?

```
@Override
    public void sendData(String userText, String userNotes) {

        //we can create the saves here as well....

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        CheckBox tv = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
        tv.setTextSize(20);
        tv.setText(userText + "  \n" + date);
        tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
        checkBoxArrayList.add(tv);

        //Handles if checkbox is pressed down, and set id for each check box
        for(int i = 0; i < checkBoxArrayList.size(); i ++){

            checkBoxArrayList.get(i).setId(i);

            checkBoxArrayList.get(i).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                    switch(motionEvent.getAction()) {

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            //here we will simply open the files unless held down

                            //when held down
                            view.postDelayed(runnable, 1250);
                            break;

                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            }

            //add checkbox passed in to the layout
            ll.addView(tv);
        }
```

Thanks to @rex I simply had a global private integer checkboxPopupCheck. I added it inside of the case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN. I can now use this integer for what I need.

```
checkboxPopupCheck = view.getId();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your onTouch Method has two parameters, the first is the view that was touched.

So doing a simple `view.getId()` would return you the same id that you set with

```
checkBoxArrayList.get(i).setId(i);
```

and that's the integer value of the ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Try this code inside your adapter where clicking the check box a new array list you have to create and add the position or the value of the holder in to the array list thus you can know the what are the items are being checked.

```html
holderItem.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    // add in to a arraylist 
                }else{
                    // remove it from arraylist
                }

            }
        });
```